# relative path for websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket, relative-path, relative-url

I have installed Apache2.2.22 and nodejs 0.10.12 succesfully in windows server 2012 r2.

I succesfully made node a windows service, using nssm, so it will always run.

Node "lives" in 8000 port and I have installed a proxy in apache's `httpd.conf` like so

```
ProxyPass /nodejs http://localhost:8000
ProxyPassReverse /nodejs http://localhost:8000
```

When I check my site in server's browser, websockets work fine.

When I check my site in my laptops browser, I get error.

I guess its caused because I create websockets like so

```
 var ci = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");
```

That's why works on server,not on my laptop. Because of the `localhost`. First, am I right?

Second. The only problem is, I dont know how to create relative paths for websockets. I have tried different syntaxes, but no luck. Please, can somebody show me how, and explain to me?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** : 
I did not set up windows server 2012 r2. A collegue did. I just uploaded the website. I made an Inbound rule in Windows Firewall, so port 8000 is open. Also ,one for port 80 (for Apache). I tried stuff like robertklep suggests, no luck. Maybe an issue of OS? (security restrictions?)

Inside `httpd.conf` I also have

```
 ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
 ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
```

Its before the node's proxy. Its about Geoserver and port 8080, which also has an inbound rule. Works just fine.

Node only works locally (having `localhost` in the URL). Locally, if I remove the `Proxy` lines from `httpd.conf`, still works.

I have no clue, how to install/configure the `proxy_wstunnel_module`. And I am not sure if I need it.

I did everything in my powers, please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

First: yes, you are right.

Second: I think WebSocket URL's always have to be absolute. To determine that URL dynamically, you can use something like this:

```
var ci = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.hostname + ':8000');
```

I'm assuming that you're not using the Node server on port 8000 to also serve the HTML files. If you are, this might also work (and is a bit shorter):

```
var ci = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.host);
```

Comment: You are right. I use apache for html and php files. I got node just to handle websockets. I will check your method and let you know

Comment: I get what your method does. Problem: the url of the site is `http://project.speak.gr/sitefolder/index.php`. `location.hostname` gives back `http://project.speak.gr`. I tried something like`ws://' + location.hostname + '/sitefolder/index.php:8000'` but, still nothing. Any idea how can I edit it?

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot that you probably want to have Apache proxy the WebSocket traffic. That might not be trivial, you'll need [a special submodule for that](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/201303.mbox/%3CDA1B7825-90BC-41C5-9F42-66C4E154D6E2@jaguNET.com%3E).

Comment: I have a proxy in Apache. What is this link about? Should I load a new module? I did not get it, sorry.

Comment: @slevin WebSockets use a special protocol. If you want to proxy that, your proxy (Apache in this case) needs to support that protocol. That's what's that module is used for. I don't think you're exposing port 8000 to the Internet directly?

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, I should add those lines `ProxyPass ws://....` or replace the existing proxy with `ProxyPass ws://...` and `ProxyPassReverse ws://`? - Yes I made an Inbound rule in Windows Firewall, so port 8000 is open. Is that an issue?

Comment: @slevin well if port 8000 is open, you can perhaps use it directly instead of having to proxy WS traffic. Try `ws://project.speak.gr:8000/` as URL for the `WebSocket` constructor (similar to my first example).